# Use Product Attribute in conditional tag

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following code which adds the price next to each variation:

```
//Add prices to variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );

function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
global $wpdb, $product;

$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

$term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

$query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

$variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

if ( $parent > 0 ) {
$_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );

//this is where you can actually customize how the price is displayed
return $term . ' <span>(' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . ')</span>';
}
return $term;

}
```

This code works perfectly.  However I would like to have that code apply only to a specific product attribute (the slug is training-level).  Is this possible with a if statement and conditional tags?

I also tried adding the following just bellow `global $wpdb, $product;` but didn't work:

```
$product_name = $product->get_attribute( 'training-level' );
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump( $product->get_attribute( 'training-level' ) );`?

Comment: Hi... Is this what you mean?  https://imgur.com/a/p5RCo

Comment: Yes. So the code you added meant `$product_name` was set to the string `Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced`. You can make an if statement based on that

Comment: Thanks @Xhynk... I'm not quite sure how to do that... Please see the image representation here: https://imgur.com/a/Eu2MU . . If I wanted to show the prices only for the three variations for Training Level, and not for Flavor,. How would I do it?  Do you mind providing an example?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added an answer I think will work for you. You might need to change the string values based on what the value of `$term` actually is

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap the "return with price" section if the `$term` variable matches a certain value.

I'm unsure what `$term` actually contains, but this should work. If not, you can modify the values in the `if` statements.

```
//Add prices to variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    $result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

    $term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;

    $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
        WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
        AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
        AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

    $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

    if( $parent > 0 ){
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );

        if( $term == 'Beginner Level' || $term == 'Intermediate Level' || $term == 'Advanced Level' ){
            //this is where you can actually customize how the price is displayed
            return $term . ' <span>(' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . ')</span>';
        } else {
            return $term;
        }
    }
    return $term;
}
```

Comment: It worked just as I wanted it.  I could not thank you enough!  Wish I could buy you a beer or a coffee.  CHeers

Comment: I won't shill my ko-fi link (might be against ToS?) - but if you could hit the little check mark to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote it, that would be excellent! Glad to help!